# Double left query with And Statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

People,

I am desperately trying to make a query that seems simple, but I am unable to master at 4.30 in the morning.. perhaps someone can offer some advice on what I am doing wrong.

The task: I have two tables, one a list of systems and another a list of certificates. I want to ensure that I list all systems and any certificates with Z85 in one column and Z86 in another. When I try my left join in access, I do not get all the rows from table 1, but I understand why. I just don't know how to make the AND statements properly.

I am using Microsoft access to get my head around it.

Can anyone help?

Here is my (failing) attempt..

```
SELECT 
  u_AllSubs.SubSystem, 
  ul_ZenCerts.[Date Accepted by Client PMT Rep] 
FROM (u_AllSubs 
LEFT JOIN ul_ZenCerts ON ((u_AllSubs.SubSystem = ul_ZenCerts.Subsystem) AND ((ul_ZenCerts.[Certificate Template]) Like "*Z85*")) 
LEFT JOIN (ul_ZenCerts AS ul_ZenCerts_1 ON ((u_AllSubs.SubSystem = ul_ZenCerts_1.Subsystem) AND ((ul_ZenCerts_1.[Certificate Template]) Like "*Z86*")));
```

Comment: Could you include the structure of your database tabes u_AllSubs and ul_ZenCerts? Could you also include some dummy data and expected results?

Comment: You state "Z85 in one column and Z86 in another." Yet you are looking in the same column, [Certificate Template]. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This might help to get the values in separate columns.  Hoping I got your field choices right, but I think you get the idea from this

```
select ul_ZenCerts, subsystem 
into #tempz1 
from  ul_ZenCerts.Subsystem z1 where  z1.[Certificate Template] Like '%Z85%' 

select ul_ZenCerts, subsystem 
into #tempz2 
from ul_ZenCerts.Subsystem z2 where z2.[Certificate Template]) Like '%Z86%'



SELECT 
  u.SubSystem, 
  z1.ul_ZenCerts,
  Z2.ul_ZenCerts 
FROM u_AllSubs u
left join #tempz1 z1 on u.SubSystem = z1.Subsystem
left join #tempz2 z2 on u.SubSystem = z2.Subsystem
```